# Highcharts multiple graphs stacked in seperate "<div>" with combine zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am looking for a basic example from Highcharts where the following is done

a. 3 separate graphs windows stacked on top of each other 
b. combine zoom option where all three separate graphs can bee zoomed for data.

what I was looking is "highstock" data where i can add more windows.

thanks,
Bilal

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this example

```
  yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            dataGrouping: {
                units: groupingUnits
            }
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/

You may use any number of y-axis i.e stacked graphs

Comment: Thanks for the code however, I have to plot the 2 data series in one graph i.e. instead of "candlestick" if I change it to "line" then 3 line series should be plotted but it doesn't plot 3 line series when i change the type. I have a series of data (price, 50day moving average, 100 day moving average, 200 day moving average) which I want to plot in the "candlestick" area.

Comment: You can plot three lines as well, just place their position properly.... I'll update fiddle for that to demonstrate

Comment: Sure. Plz, i will keep checking the fiddle link

Answer (score 1):

@Bial I have created a fiddle for your use-case, view the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/4b33pvc2/ Its having 3 series with navigator.

code for each series is like below :

```
{
                      name : 'critical alarm',
                      data :data.criticalAlarmCountTimeseries,
                      id : 'critical',
                      zIndex : 1,
                      lineWidth:3,
                      color:'red',
                      yAxis: 0 ,
                      marker : {
                          enabled : false

                      } 
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) on xAxis chart and call [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) on the other charts to "zoom".

```
                    events: {
                         afterSetExtremes: function() {
                             if (controllingChart == "chart3") {
                                    var xMin = this.chart.xAxis[0].min;
                                    var xMax = this.chart.xAxis[0].max;
                                    chart1.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin,
                                                                xMax,
                                                                true);
                                    chart2.xAxis[0].setExtremes(xMin,
                                                                xMax,
                                                                true);
                                }
                           }
                     }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gv7Tg/33/

Comment: Sure thanks! I would prefer the changes in "candlestick and volume" graph which is presented above.

Comment: The rule is the same, change a type of series. You can also use single chart with 3 yAxis, then you avoid synchronisation problem.